# Redirecting via 301 subdomain to URI/URL configuration error in NGINX

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

Trying to get a simple subdomain redirect in NGINX to a URI/URL path. At this point I want to get nginx.somedomain.com to redirect permanently to nginx.somedomain.com/sample/redirection.html. The config below I have in the nginx.conf file but isn't working. I've restarted the server, but still no go. Specifically it errors out and shows this as invalid in the nginx.conf file. Where should this go and also is this even correct?

```
server {
  server_name  nginx.somedomain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://nginx.somedomain.com/sample/redirection.html permanent;
}
```

Thanks for any assist!

Comment: Show full error message. And this config is useless, it willl create infinite loop,

Comment: Yeah, I found that out the hard way.  :-/  The solution as shown below however works fine, no validation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow best practices and use the [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) directive:

```
server {
        server_name nginx.somedomain.com;
        return 301 http://nginx.somedomain.com/sample/redirection.html;
}
```